# How to select the last paragraph element ONLY if no other elements follow after her? (CSS selector question)

Tags: html, css, layout, css-selectors, selector

How can I select the last paragraph `<p>` element, if and only its the last and lowest HTML element of the `<article>` element?

I don't want to use `.classes` or `#id's`. A CSS selector should automatically find and select the `<p>` element.

In my demo, in the first section, the last `<p>` element should be selected, while in the second section the last `<p>` element should not be selected.

```css
article p:last-of-type{
    background: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<article>
   <column>
     <p>Text</p>
     <p>Text</p>
     <p>Text</p>
     <p>This paragraph should <b>NOT</b> be selected, if this would be the last paragraph on a page.</p>
     <div>Text</div>
     <div>Text</div>
  </column>

  <hr>

  <column>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>This paragraph <b>SHOULD</b> be selected, if this was the last paragraph on the page.</p>
  </column>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options for you. Main thing selecting the first `article` child.

```css
article:nth-child(1) p:last-of-type {
  background: yellow;
}

article:nth-child(1) p:last-child {
  background: yellow;
}

article:first-of-type p:last-of-type {
  background: yellow;
}

article:first-child p:nth-child(4) {
  background: yellow;
}

article:first-child p:last-of-type {
  background: yellow;
}

article:first-child p:last-child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>This paragraph <b>SHOULD</b> be selected.</p>
</article>

<br><br>
<hr><br><br>

<article>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>But this paragraph should <b>NOT</b> be selected.</p>
  <div>Text</div>
  <video src="/ufo landing right in the middle of a demonstration full hd footage.mpg" alt="" />
  <img src="/ufo interview with human in 12k resolution.mpg" />
  <div>Text</div>
</article>
```

Version 2:

```css
column:last-of-type p:last-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<article>
   <column>
     <p>Text</p>
     <p>Text</p>
     <p>Text</p>
     <p>This paragraph should <b>NOT</b> be selected.</p>
     <div>Text</div>
     <video src="/ufo landing right in the middle of a demonstration full hd footage.mpg" alt="" />
     <img src="/ufo interview with human in 12k resolution.mpg" />
    <div>Text</div>
  </column>

  <hr>

  <column>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>This paragraph <b>SHOULD</b> be selected.</p>
  </column>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I rephrased my question I made a small mistake: the item should only be selected if its the lowest and last <p> on the page so to say.

Comment: Interesting point. What would be the penalty of using custom tags, when they are nested inside valid elements?

Comment: Thanks Kameron for all the answers. Im looking into it now. The actual case is more complex and difficult to simplify here, but with your elaborate answers it should be done. Answer accepted!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
You can use `:last-child` on your `p` tag on your

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```css
column p:last-child{
    background: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<article>
   <column>
     <p>Text</p>
     <p>Text</p>
     <p>Text</p>
     <p>This paragraph should <b>NOT</b> be selected.</p>
     <div>Text</div>
     <div>Text</div>
  </column>

  <hr>

  <column>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>This paragraph <b>SHOULD</b> be selected.</p>
  </column>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I rephrased my question I made a small mistake: the item should only be selected if its the lowest and last <p> on the page so to say.

Comment: modified, is this what do you need?

Comment: Thank you.  The actual example is more complex, difficult to simplify it here. I am looking into it now.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `first-of-type` to `article` in CSS

```css
article:first-of-type p:last-of-type{
    background: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<article>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>This paragraph <b>SHOULD</b> be selected.</p>
</article>

<br><br><hr><br><br>

<article>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>But this paragraph should <b>NOT</b> be selected.</p>
  <div>Text</div>
  <video src="/ufo landing right in the middle of a demonstration full hd footage.mpg" alt="" />
  <img src="/ufo interview with human in 12k resolution.mpg" />
  <div>Text</div>
<etcettera>

</article>
```

Comment: I changed the order of the paragraphs in my sample. My mistake. BUT +1 because  your answer brought me on the idea to add `article:last-of-type` before the `p:last-of-type` ! Its almost working now!